# Launching with snapshot based volume fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to launch an instance, and I'm adding an EBS volume on top of the root volume.
In the extra EBS volume, I'm specifying a snapshot I created.
When I click "Launch", I immediately get the following error:

```
snapshotId can only be modified on EBS devices
```

Can you explain the problem please?

Comment: This question would be a better fit for http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving to a bigger instance type solved the problem.

Answer (score 86):

Ran into the same issue while mounting EBS volume to `/dev/sdc` on an instance (c3.2xlarge) using HVM image.

The solution which worked for me was to use an available AWS recommended device name e.g. `/dev/sdf`. AWS recommended device name for attaching EBS volume is `/dev/sd[f-p]`

> For Linux/Unix instance recommended device names are `/dev/sd[f-p]`

Source: [AWS Block Device Naming on Linux Instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/device_naming.html)

Comment: In my case, choosing a bigger instance type didn't help, then I decided to try to change default **/dev/sdb**  into  **/dev/sdf** and... voilà! it went fine.  Now I should try again with a **T1.nano** instance

Comment: I was not expecting this to work but it did, I've never seen this before when creating ec2 from snapshot, it must have something to do with an ec2 setting that's causing this

Comment: why is it still set by default to sdb after 7 years????

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, described it here [Amazon Launch Template - Updated AMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52102698/amazon-launch-template-updated-ami/56146598#56146598) .

tl;dr
You need to keep AMI and volume's sizes the same. I had 15 GB AMI and 8 GB volume.

Answer (score 0):

Error Description is not correct, however Maxim Kogan is correct, Moving to larger instance solves the problem. 
It appears, that the storage capacity of T1 instance is very little.