# Creating a Launch Template from Instance that has Volume updated compared to original AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, templates, amazon-ec2

We need a way to launch an instance as quick as possible, and I was very happy when I saw this new Launch Template feature from AWS. However, it is actually bothering me more than I expected.

**Current position:**

- I created an instance (call it instance A) from a Community AMI.
- I modified that instance's volume (volume AA) the way
- I want it to be (calling this state of A updated-A) I want a Launch Template that
  will launch me an instance (B, C, as many as I want) that is exact
  copy of thus updated-A instance.

**What I did**

Right click on instance A/updated-A, Create Template from Instance. Template was created successfully, but when I launched a new instance (B) using that template, it didn't hold the updated volume, it had the volume in the state it was when I first created the original instance from AMI. Then I realized that in the template wizard, in the Storage section, the template is still referring to a snapshot of AA - of the original instance A - meaning that the EBS for instance B (this volume being BA) was created from a snapshot that holds the original AA volume (calling that snapshot AAA).

**What I did next**

So I created a new snapshot of the AA volume - in its updated state, calling this snapshot (BBA). Recreated the Launch Template, but it lead to the same result when I tried to create instance C (copy of updated-A, as well), as in the Launch Template wizard, AWS interface won't let me change the snapshot ID to BBA.

**My final try**

So I created a new volume (CCC) from snapshot BBA. Detached volume AA from Instance A. Attached volume CCC to instance A as sdb and created Template from that instance (call it updated-AC instance). When I tried creating instance from that template, the operation failed because it didn't have the root device - but, the snapshot ID (BBA) was the one that I wanted. Encouragement. So I went and detached and reattached as root, i.e. dev/sda1. Create Template from Instance.

The actual problem:

When I try to launch instance from this newest template (that holds appropriate snapshot ID), I get error:

```
snapshotId cannot be modified on root device
```

And I am at a loss now, have no idea what to try next... Please help.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I could agree with that, but neither is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52102698/amazon-launch-template-updated-ami After reading a couple like that, I asked here. Please tell me if there is a better place to post the question. Thanks!

Comment: See [Where can I ask questions on cloud computing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117646/218578)